# Can I publish a book at 14?

Tags: fiction, young-author

I'm currently thinking of writing a murder mystery series with three books that I am planning it's called Tailor Shop Mysteries and I have three titles and my family in willing to help me with the making of it and proof reading. So if my family thinks I may be ready can I get them published under a pen name as e-books when I finished them.

Comment: Hi Nate and welcome to Writing!  You're not the first young author who's asked about this, so we've got some answers for you already in the linked question.  There's nothing wrong with your question being marked as a duplicate; the goal is to get you answers, so I hope the ones there help you.  Good luck with your series, and don't let anybody tell you you're too young.  If you have more questions as you work on your books, please ask them here.